# draggable&droppable jquery comparison id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm looking for option how to comparison id in draggable&dropabble elements. It's my first journey with jquery.

Actually I have (fragments):

```
$(".letter").draggable();
$(".simpleSlot").droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    var idDrag = ui.draggable.attr("id");
    var idDrop = $this.attr("id");
    $("#TEST").text("idDrag:" + idDrag + "; idDrop:" + idDrop);
    if(idDrag == idDrop){ alert("Done!"); }
  }
});
```

Droppable element:

```
var letter = $("<div class=\"letter\" id=\""+divId+"\"></div>").text(splitedWord[i]);

$("#divId").css({
  left: positionX, top: positionY
});

$("#mixedWord").append(letter);
```

Draggable element is generated the same way.

And my css for droppable:

```
.letter{
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flipclock/libs/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flipclock/flipclock.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <style>
        #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="area">
    <div id="time">Time:</div>
    <div id="mixedWord"><!--here goes random word as simple letters in simple divs-->  </div>
    <div id="slots"></div>
    <div id="height"></div>
    <div id="width"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

MY PROBLEMS:

1. Draggable works. But when I drop something on droppable element - I can't move it more. It cannot be that.
2. It doesn't change #TEST - so it means drop doesn't work. Why?
3. And I don't have alert.

Comment: Can you provide a live example or your HTML for this problem? Also, there a couple of undefined variables, at leas tin the context of your snippets. Take a look in your console. Did the drop event say anything about `$this`?

Comment: All variables are right defined, I just didn't want to show all code, it's long. But I'm sure they're right.

Comment: Okey, I see. First problem with $this. It was taken from documentation so I didn't think it can be wrong.

Comment: Taking a look in the doc, it doesn't say `$this` but it says `$(this)` http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#default

Comment: Stupid mistakes are the hadest to find ;/ I verify is it work when I will be in home. Thanks!